# How to define a default value for a column after a cast in a pgloader script?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration

Let's say I'm migrating a MySQL database to PostgreSQL with pgloader, using the default sample on the [official website](http://pgloader.io/howto/mysql.html):

```
load database  
     from      mysql://root@localhost/sakila  
     into postgresql:///sakila  

 WITH include drop, create tables, no truncate,  
      create indexes, reset sequences, foreign keys  

  SET maintenance_work_mem to '128MB', work_mem to '12MB', search_path to 'sakila'  

 CAST type datetime to timestamptz  
                drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null,  
      type date drop not null drop default using zero-dates-to-null  

 MATERIALIZE VIEWS film_list, staff_list  

 -- INCLUDING ONLY TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~/film/, 'actor'  
 -- EXCLUDING TABLE NAMES MATCHING ~<ory>  

 BEFORE LOAD DO  
 $$ create schema if not exists sakila; $$;
```

Let's also assume that in the table 'foo', I have a column 'bar' with DATETIME type, and I want to set a new default value of '2015-01-01 00:00:00' when I migrate it to PostgreSQL (the old default value in MySQL is '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

How can I define this in the pgloader migration script? I tried the following line just after the CAST keyword, but it is throwing an error right here:

```
column foo.bar to timestamp set default "2015-01-01 00:00:00",
                                        ^ (Could not parse WHITESPACE)
```

And I couldn't find anything about default values in the [reference docs](http://pgloader.io/howto/pgloader.1.html).

Comment: If the only problem is with spaces, try `set default '2015-01-01'`.

Comment: Nope, it still does not work. I suspect the whole `set default` declaration has to use a different syntax, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: So try in another section: `after load do $$ alter table foo alter bar set default '2015-01-01' $$` (I do not use pgloader, just read the manual).

Comment: I know I can do it with a regular query after loading the schema. I just wanted to avoid doing it there, since I got about 80 tables in the database for migration which need this default value modification, and hoped for an easier approach than having to list every single table :)

Comment: Ok. If you want to set the same default for all timestamp columns in all tables (in a database or schema), this could be done with postgres do statement.

Answer (score 0):

CAST type datetime2 to "timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NOW()" drop default

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).